# OkHttp3 Brotli interceptor fails to give proper string

Tags: okhttp, java-17, brotli

This is how I tried:

```
@SneakyThrows
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OkHttpClient ok = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(BrotliInterceptor.INSTANCE).build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/seach?q=apple&token=secretToken")
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "br")
            .build();

    Call call = ok.newCall(request);

    // how do i print the body?

    Response resp = call.execute();
    System.out.println(resp.body().string());
    System.out.println(resp.body().source().readString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

This is what I get:

```
1�  
�+�哛�,�     �5����,��}��0�,N7S螞
�`�z�^�)OG�+u�+16�Z�ǵؔW�B*�z0 ў�J'���.��LL��H^�aL#��q\lZW>��Mƚ�GH`:�:@B�l��1�rf{즫����Q���B{ |��JUK���Y>y����+�Ů�jf�����$��
```

What I am supposed to get is this:

```
{"count":22,"result":[{"description":"Apple","displaySymbol":"A3LHSP.BE" ...
```

As a workaround I am able to do this:

```
BufferedSource buffer = Okio.buffer(Okio.source(new BrotliInputStream(resp.body().source().inputStream())));
String content = buffer.readUtf8();
System.out.println(content);
```

After this workaround, it works properly.
But my question is why is this not working with .string() method as it usually works? I wanted to go with brotli but it seems okhttp support is poor for that.

Can anyone show me how to properly configure brotli?
I tried addInterceptor() instead of addNetworkInterceptor() also. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the encoding yourself.

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/a05ee927ebba6c23b9dd76c839e99ae3134bad02/okhttp-brotli/src/test/java/okhttp3/brotli/BrotliTestMain.kt#L23

```
  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addInterceptor(BrotliInterceptor)
      .build()
```